# HM CMB: Role Select

Tags: custom-field, metabox, user-roles

I'm using human made's custom meta boxes framework (https://github.com/humanmade/Custom-Meta-Boxes).  I want to add a select drop down in my metabox wich is populated from the roles on my WP site.  How would i populate a select field with the current roles on my site?

I was trying to us a post_select field and WP_Query the roles, but not sure if that's possible:

```
array( 
        'id'       => $prefix . 'role', 
        'name'     => 'Role', 
        'type'     => 'post_select', 
        'use_ajax' => false,
        'query' => array( 'wp_roles' => array('get_names') )
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a list of roles in the `$wp_roles` WordPress global object.

Set `$wp_roles` to a global at the top of your method of function:

```
global $wp_roles;
```

Use a [Select Field](https://github.com/humanmade/Custom-Meta-Boxes/wiki/Select-Field) to populate the options:

```
array(
    'id'       => $prefix . 'role',
    'name'     => 'Role',
    'type'     => 'select',
    'use_ajax' => false,
    'options'  => $wp_roles->get_names(),
),
```

Note: I didn't install Humanmade CMB to test this code.

Comment: Better use `$roles = new WP_Roles(); $roles->get_names();`, which is more reliable. It checks and in case sets the global as well.